# FormatException was unhandled (int.Parse)

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, formatexception

I have:

```
    private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsInt32())     
        {
            txtScores.Text += txtScore.Text + " ";
            txtScore.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

and:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidData())
        {
            List<string> result = txtScores.Text.Split(' ').ToList();
            student = new Student(txtName.Text, result.Select(int.Parse).ToList());
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

I'm trying to use my btnAddScore to build a string of scores from my txtScore to my txtScores. This I believe I'm doing correctly. Then I'm converting that string into a list by Parsing each element with " ". I then further convert the List < string > into a List < int >. No compiler errors but a runtime error of "FormatException was undandled" and points to (int.Parse). I've read that int.Parse will cause this if used on an empty string, but I don't see how that's the case if it is.

Comment: What was the value of `txtScores.Text` at the time of exception

Comment: use int.TryParse. I suspect the string that you are trying to convert is not in the numerical format

Comment: put some details of IsInt32 method

Comment: I commented out IsInt32 and ran it without a validator(that's what IsInt32 is, which I'm sure you knew). Still have the same result.         

private bool IsInt32(){try {Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text); return true; } catch (FormatException) {MessageBox.Show(txtScore.Tag + "must be an integer."); txtScore.Focus(); return false;}}

Comment: I can enter in a string of scores in the format I want directly in the txtScores {100 20 40} and it works just fine. I'm supposed to be entering the same scores in the same box with the txtScores.Text += txtScore.Text + " "; It is entering it as a string is it not?

Comment: I removed the .Text from the txtScore + " "; and when I add it to the list I get "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. Text:" This means my validator is messing with my string?

Comment: Take a look at EdaurdoS's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243200/formatexception-was-unhandled-int-parse/22243317#22243317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are appending a white space the "Split" method returns an empty element at the end wich you are not expecting, add na option "SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries" (from head, check if it is the correct name) and your code will work.

Comment: +1, good catch! Will probably have to be called like `txtScores.Text.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TryParse` like this,

```
student = new Student(txtName.Text, result.Select(s =>
    {
        int res = 0;
        return int.TryParse(s, out res) ? res : 0;
    }).ToList());
```

This code will avoid the exceptions you are getting and if it can not parse any value it will set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that one of your string is not valid int after splitting by space (' '). 
I would suggest to consider only those scores which are valid number.

Let's consider below scores separated by space

> 111 123 **12x** 212 1454

here **12x** is not valid so you should reject this number. and get only four valid numbers as shown in below code sample :

```
var scores = "111 123 12x 212 1454";
var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");
var studentScore = scores.Split(' ').Where(a => regex.IsMatch(a)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

This error is easily debugged by setting a break point in Visual Studio on the following line:

```
student = new Student(txtName.Text, result.Select(int.Parse).ToList())
```

...and then inspecting `result` list manually. One of the strings definitely is not a parseable int.

In short: You have a good error message and should be able to find this error quickly by using standard debugging techniques.

Comment: This seems more like a comment

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: You're right, but then there's also that with "give a man a fish and you'll feed him for a day(...)". In this case one would quickly have spotted the culprit extra space by inspecting the result collection.